# Salesforce to Quickbooks using oAuth 1.0

Tags: oauth, quickbooks

I am trying to connect to Quickbooks online from apex. I have created an App in IPP and got consumer key, consumer secret, Auth token, Auth Token secret. Now I am confused how to used them to connect Quickbook and make API calls. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using this code and keep on getting "Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401"

```
String endpoint='https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/11111111/account/11';


Http http=new Http();
HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Accept','application/xml');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth');

String body = String.format(
'oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_signature_method={1}&oauth_signature={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_nonce={4}&oauth_version={5}&oauth_token={6}',
new String[] {
    'yyyyy6NRbFIa1njAUiZUxxxxxxxxxx',    // the key
    'HMAC-SHA1',    // the method
    'yyyyy%2B%2BuearXdD5jORmJHcxxxxxxxxxx',     // the signature
    '1400670420',             // the timestamp
    'N70lhvz7ncW',          // the nonce
    '1.0',          // the version
    'yyyyywh7sxI31NTbZHA3BzRy4i5FHXOriQdRDyxxxxxxxxxx' //the token
    });
    req.setBody(body);   
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('GET');   
    HttpResponse res;
    res = http.send(req);
```

Regards,
Ashfaq Ahmad

Comment: This is a bit open ended as is... what have you tried so far? I would have thought Quickbooks would have some getting started guides to follow.

Comment: They Have, but samples show only how to connect using SDK's of Java, .NET etc. They do not have a complete end to end example for REST Api.

Comment: You should read and try out connected app example before integrating it with Quickbooks to make sure that it will fit into your requirements. Here is one example of connected apps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/integrating-force-com-and-heroku-apps